# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $|H|>\sqrt{|G|}$ and $|K|>\sqrt{|G|}$. Show that $|H\cap K|>1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Problem.** $|H|>\sqrt{|G|}$ and $|K|>\sqrt{|G|}$ and $H,K\leq G$ where $G$ is a finite group. Prove $|H\cap K|>1$.

$$|HK|=\dfrac{|H| |K|}{|H\cap K|}>\dfrac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}\Rightarrow |H\cap K|>\dfrac{|G|}{|HK|}.$$
Now I need to show that $|HK|\geq |G|$, right? But I'm confused how to! I tried to use this theorem that says 

> Let $H,K\leq G$ where $G$ is a finite group. And $H\cap K={e}$. Then
$$|HK|=|H||K|.$$

But then I came across contradictions. What is *your* solution?

Comment: Since $HK\subset G$ you automatically have $|HK|\le |G|$, that is, $|G|/|HK|\ge 1$. This is what you want in order to prove your claim.

Comment: @Teri That's right, thanks! I've not focused enough there. Post this as an answer so I can pick it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your argument up to the point $$ |H\cap K| >\frac{|G|}{|HK|}$$ is correct. After that you get needlessly confuse. Since $HK\subset G$ we automatically have $$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}>1$$ from which the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map of sets $f:H \times K \to G$ defined by $f(h, k) = hk$. Since $|G| < |H|\,|K| = |H\times K|$, the map $f$ cannot be injective. Hence there exist distinct $(h, k), (h', k')\in H\times K$ with $hk = h'k'$. Thus $h^{-1}h'\in H$ and $(k')^{-1}k\in K$ are equal, and so $h^{-1}h' \not = 1$ lies in $H\cap K$.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Teri , I've got it:

$$HK\subseteq G\Rightarrow |HK|\leq |G|\Rightarrow\dfrac{|G|}{|HK|}\geq1.$$